# Посчитать сумму значений столбца без дубликатов

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Значения этого столбца ссылаются на определённую ячейку из банковской выписки, которую я на отдельном листе вставил. Мне нужна формула для автоматического подсчёта суммы уникальных значений. Искал сейчас примерно часа 3, но так ничего и не сработало, а делать рядом отдельную таблицу с уникальными значениями не хочется. Если можно будет эту таблицу с уникальными значениями автоматически пополнять, то это ещё окей. Я с Excel не так давно работаю, помогите, пожалуйста)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imzvS.png)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваши значения к примеру находятся в столбце А2 и ниже (А1 - заголовок), то в любом столбце к примеру В2 ставьте формулу:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A$2:A2;A2)=1;A2;"")
```

И скопируйте её вниз на весь столбец. Так вы получите, в этом столбце, только уникальные числа. Ну а как посчитать сумму столбца, думаю разберетесь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень сильно облегичло работу)

Answer (score 0):

Без создания доп. столбца. Формула массива:

```
=СУММ(ЕСЛИ(ПОИСКПОЗ(B2:B50;B2:B50;)=СТРОКА(B2:B50)-1;B2:B50))
```

Диапазон должен быть указан от первой до последней ячейки с данными (т.е. без пустых ячеек).

Ввод формулы массива завершается тремя клавишами - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`